# How do I test the API behavior when mock returns unordered collection Map?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5, assertj

I have an API, API calls a service which returns `Map<String, List<String>>`, API converts it to List and returns it.

```
public List<EmployeeWrapper> getEmployees(int id) {
    Map<Integer, List<String>> employees = employeeRepository.getEmployees(id);
    return employees.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new EmployeeWrapper(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now, I need to write a test case to cover this behavior, but the problem here is `Mock` returns `HashMap` and the order of `List<EmployeeWrapper>` could be different on each invocation.

```
@Test
void testEmployeeService() {
    // when
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = Mockito.mock(EmployeeRepository.class);
 
    Map<Integer, List<String>> employeeIdsToEmployee = 
            Map.of(1, List.of("HR", "Account"), 2, List.of("Marketing"));
    Mockito.when(employeeRepository.getEmployees(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(employeeIdsToEmployee);
    
    // call service
    List<EmployeeWrapper> employees = employeeService.getEmployees(10);
    
    // assert
    assertThat(employees).isNotNull().hasSize(2);
    EmployeeWrapper employeeWrapper1 = employees.get(0);
    EmployeeWrapper employeeWrapper2 = employees.get(1);

    assertThat(employeeWrapper1).isNotNull().extracting("id", "departments")
            .containsExactly(1, List.of("HR", "Account"));
    assertThat(employeeWrapper2).isNotNull().extracting("id", "departments")
            .containsExactly(2, List.of("Marketing"));
}
```

The problem here is `employees.get(0)` and `employees.get(1)` wouldn't be always the same object as the employee List is built using an unordered collection.

is there a better way to test if the behavior of an API is dependent on unordered collection?

Comment: Did you try using a LinkedHashMap in your test to preserve order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AssertJ's assertions for iterables has a 'containsExactlyInAnyOrder' method.

You have to start the assertion on the list:

```
assertThat(employees)
         .extracting("id", "departments")
         .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
            tuple(1, List.of("HR", "Account")),
            tuple(2, List.of("Marketing")));
```

BTW, the extracting method also supports lambda's, so it can be:

```
assertThat(employees)
         .extracting(
              EmployeeWrapper::getId,
              EmployeeWrapper::getDepartments)
         .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
              tuple(1, List.of("HR", "Account")),
              tuple(2, List.of("Marketing")));
```